# Airflow : Passing a dynamic value to Sub DAG operator

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to Airflow.
I have come across a scenario, where Parent DAG need to pass some dynamic number (let's say `n`) to Sub DAG.
Where as SubDAG will use this number to dynamically create `n` parallel tasks.

Airflow documentation doesn't cover a way to achieve this. So I have explore couple of ways :

### Option - 1(Using xcom Pull)

I have tried to pass as a xcom value, but for some reason SubDAG is not resolving to the passed value.

**Parent Dag File**

```
def load_dag(**kwargs):
    number_of_runs = json.dumps(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['number_of_runs'])
    dag_data = json.dumps({
        "number_of_runs": number_of_runs
    })
    return dag_data

# ------------------ Tasks ------------------------------
load_config = PythonOperator(
    task_id='load_config',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=load_dag,
    dag=dag)


t1 = SubDagOperator(
    task_id=CHILD_DAG_NAME,
    subdag=sub_dag(PARENT_DAG_NAME, CHILD_DAG_NAME, default_args, "'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='load_config') }}'" ),
    default_args=default_args,
    dag=dag,
)
```

**Sub Dag File**

```
def sub_dag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, args, num_of_runs):
    dag_subdag = DAG(
        dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None)

    variabe_names = {}

    for i in range(num_of_runs):
        variabe_names['task' + str(i + 1)] =  DummyOperator(
        task_id='dummy_task',
        dag=dag_subdag,
    )

    return dag_subdag
```

### Option - 2

I have also tried to pass `number_of_runs` as a global variable, which was not working.

### Option - 3

Also we tried to write this value to a data file. But sub DAG is throwing `File doesn't exist error`. This might be because we are dynamically generating this file.

Can some one help me with this.

Comment: Option 3 will not work if you are in multi worker system, where in your load_config and sub dag runs in different boxes

Comment: It have to be added dag_id='master_id" to xcom_pull

Answer (score 2):

I've done it with Option 3. The key is to return a valid dag with no tasks, if the file does not exist. So load_config will generate a file with your number of tasks or more information if needed. Your subdag factory would look something like:

```
def subdag(...):
    sdag = DAG('%s.%s' % (parent, child), default_args=args, schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1))
    file_path = "/path/to/generated/file"
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        data_file = open(file_path)
        list_tasks = data_file.readlines()
        for task in list_tasks:
            DummyOperator(
                  task_id='task_'+task,
                  default_args=args,
                  dag=sdag,
            )
    return sdag
```

At dag generation you will see a subdag with No tasks. At dag execution, after load_config is done, you can see you dynamically generated subdag

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should work if you just change the call to `xcom_pull` to include the `dag_id` of the parent dag. By default the `xcom_pull` call will look for the `task_id` `'load_config'` in its own dag which doesnt exist.

so change the x_com call macro to:

```
subdag=sub_dag(PARENT_DAG_NAME, CHILD_DAG_NAME, default_args, "'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='load_config', dag_id='" + PARENT_DAG_NAME + "' }}'" ),
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the Jinja template isn't evaluated when calling sub_dag().

Comment: Jinja2 template string was not rendered because Airflow will only render if fields used are registered as template fields in Operator. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#jinja-templating `You can also use Jinja templating with nested fields, as long as these nested fields are marked as templated in the structure they belong to: fields registered in template_fields property will be submitted to template substitution`

Answer (score 0):

If the filename you are writing to is not dynamic (e.g. you are writing over the same file over and over again for each task instance), Jaime's answer will work:

```
file_path = "/path/to/generated/file"
```

But if you need a unique filename or want different content written to the file by each task instance for tasks executed in parallel, airflow will not work for this case, since there is no way to pass the execution date or variable outside of a template. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow/51951365#51951365).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51977800/9488397), in which I describe a way to create a task dynamically based on the results of a previously executed task using xcoms and subdags.