# Airflow PythonOperator inside PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

How can I run a PythonOperator inside another one PythonOperator?

The idea is: to call "main" function as a PythonOperator and then run a few other PythonOperators inside and scheduler them

The code is:

```
def printFunction(value):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(value)

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        task_2 = PythonOperator(
                        task_id='loop_task_2'+str(i),
                        python_callable = printFunction,
                        op_kwargs = {'value':i},
                        dag=dag,
                )
        task_3 = PythonOperator(
                        task_id='loop_task_3'+str(i),
                        python_callable = printFunction,
                        op_kwargs = {'value':i},
                        dag=dag,
                )
        task_2>>task_3

task = PythonOperator(
                        task_id='tor_task',
                        python_callable = main,
                        op_kwargs = {},
                        dag=dag,
                )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are expecting that Airflow will create these operators/tasks in the UI but that is not going to happen. With that code you will have only `tor_task` in the UI. It's not very clear what you are trying to do but it seems that it would be better to just call `printFunction` directly in the loop.

In any case if you must use operator inside operator you should call the `execute()` method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168908/14624409) for more information

Comment: Sorry that my description is not clear. I want my PythonOperator call other PythonOperators in loop and them should be paralleled. That's what I need