# How to send multiple emails using EmailOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to send individual emails to a list of users using an EmailOperator inside a python loop but currently the emails are not being sent. The dag doesn't return any error which makes me believe the EmailOperator is not being called.

*Code*

```
@dag(schedule_interval=None, tags=['Send multiple emails testing'], default_args=default_args)
def multiple_email_send_test_dag():

    @task   
    def multiple_email_send_test():
        email_list = ['user1@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com']
        for i in range(len(email_list)):
            EmailOperator(
                task_id=f'send_success_email_test_no_{i}', 
                to=str(email_list[i]),
                subject='Email Header',
                html_content= f"""
                        Hi {email_list[i]}, <br>
                        <p>This is the body of the email</p>
                        <br> Thank You. <br>
                    """
            ) 
    
    # Dummy Operators
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    # The pipeline
    start >> multiple_email_send_test() >> end

dag = multiple_email_send_test_dag()
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of calling operator inside operator. The `EmailOperator` isn't executing - all it does is just initialize the constructor of the class. The logic of actually sending the email is in the `execute()` function of the class.

---

**DON'T DO THIS - BAD PRACTICE**:

Let me first clarify that if you want to make your current code work you must call the `execute()`  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168908/14624409) for more information about it.

```
@task   
def multiple_email_send_test():
    email_list = ['user1@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com']
    for i in range(len(email_list)):
        e = EmailOperator(
            task_id=f'send_success_email_test_no_{i}', 
            to=str(email_list[i]),
            subject='Email Header',
            html_content= f"""
                    Hi {email_list[i]}, <br>
                    <p>This is the body of the email</p>
                    <br> Thank You. <br>
                """
        ) 
        e.exectue(dict())
```

---

**How you should solve it**:

**Option 1:**
Since `EmailOperator` sends 1 email to all addresses and it's different behavior than what you wish. You can just create a custom operator `IndvidualEmailOpeator` that accept a list of emails and send to each address individual mail. By doing so you won't need to wrap the operator with `PythonOperator` / task decorator thus you can just use the operator you created directly.

**Option 2:**

Note that `EmailOperator` is simply calling [send_email](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/602abe8394fafe7de54df7e73af56de848cdf617/airflow/operators/email.py#L75-L86), so you can just use the function directly without the operator thus avoiding the issue of operator inside operator:

```
@task   
def multiple_email_send_test():
    from airflow.utils.email import send_email
    email_list = ['user1@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com']
    for i in range(len(email_list)):
        send_email(
            to=str(email_list[i]),
            subject='Email Header',
            html_content= f"""
                    Hi {email_list[i]}, <br>
                    <p>This is the body of the email</p>
                    <br> Thank You. <br>
                """
        )
```