# S3KeySensor in Airflow 2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, sensors

I have a dag called `my_dag.py` that utilizes the S3KeySensor in Airflow 2 to check if a s3 key exists. When I use the sensor directly inside the dag, it works:

```
with TaskGroup('check_exists') as check_exists: 
    
  path = 's3://my-bucket/data/my_file'
  poke_interval = 30
  timeout = 60*60
  mode = 'reschedule'
  dependency_name = 'my_file'

  S3KeySensor(
    task_id = 'check_' + dependency_name + '_exists',
    bucket_key = path,
    poke_interval = poke_interval,
    timeout = timeout,
    mode = mode
  )
```

The log of the above looks like:

```
[2022-05-03, 19:51:26 UTC] {s3.py:105} INFO - Poking for key : s3://my-bucket/data/my_file
[2022-05-03, 19:51:26 UTC] {base_aws.py:90} INFO - Retrieving region_name from Connection.extra_config['region_name']
[2022-05-03, 19:51:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1701} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
```

This is correct. The reschedule is expected, because the file does not exist yet.

However, I want to check any number of paths in other dags, so I moved the sensor into a function called `test` in another file called `helpers.py`. I use a python operator in `my_dag.py` within the task group that calls `test`. It looks like this:

```
with TaskGroup('check_exists') as check_exists:

  path = 's3://my-bucket/data/my_file'
  dependency_name = 'my_file'

  wait_for_dependencies = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'wait_for_my_file',
    python_callable = test,
    op_kwargs = {
      'dependency_name': dependency_name,
      'path': path
    },
    dag = dag
  )

  wait_for_dependencies
```

The function `test` in `helpers.py` looks like:

```
def test(dependency_name, path, poke_interval = 30, timeout = 60 * 60, mode = 'reschedule'):

    S3KeySensor(
        task_id = 'check_' + dependency_name + '_exists',
        bucket_key = path,
        poke_interval = poke_interval,
        timeout = timeout,
        mode = mode
    )
```

However, when I run the dag, the step is marked as success even though the file is not there. The logs show:

```
[2022-05-03, 20:07:54 UTC] {python.py:175} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2022-05-03, 20:07:54 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1282} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
```

It seems airflow doesn't like using a sensor via a python operator. Is this true? Or am I doing something wrong?

My goal is to loop through multiple paths and check if each one exists. However, I do this in other dags, which is why I'm putting the sensor in a function that resides in another file.

If there are alternative ideas to doing this, I'm open!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "My goal is to loop through multiple paths and check if each one exists." You can forward a list of keys to check for the `bucket_key` argument to the `S3KeySensor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as you expect.
You created a case of operator inside operator. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72043564/how-to-send-multiple-emails-using-emailoperator-in-airflow/72044151#72044151) for information about what this means.

In your case you wrapped the `S3KeySensor` with `PythonOperator`. This means that when the `PythonOperator` runs it only execute the init function of `S3KeySensor` - it doesn't invoke the logic of the operator itself.
Using operator inside operator is a bad practice.

Your case is even more extreme as you are trying to use sensor inside operator. Sensors need to invoke the `poke()` function for every poking cycle.
To simplify - You can not enjoy the power of Sensor with `mode = 'reschedule'` when you set them as you did because reschedule means that you want to release the worker if condition is not met yet but `PythonOperator` doesn't know how to do that.

**How to solve your issue:**

**Option 1:**

From the code you showed you can simply do:

```
with TaskGroup('check_exists') as check_exists:
    
  path = 's3://my-bucket/data/my_file'
  dependency_name = 'my_file'

  S3KeySensor(
    task_id='check_' + dependency_name + '_exists',
    bucket_key=path,
    poke_interval=30,
    timeout=60 * 60,
    mode='reschedule'
  )
```

I didn't see a reason why this can't work for you.

**Option 2:**

If for some reason option 1 is not good for you then create a custom sensor that accept also `dependency_name`, `path` and use it like any other operator.
I didn't test it but something like the following should work:

```
class MyS3KeySensor(S3KeySensor):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        dependency_name:str = None,
        path: str = None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.task_id = task_id = 'check_' + dependency_name + '_exists'
        self.bucket_name = path
```

Comment: I created a separate question as a continuation of this one -- could you check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147281/dynamic-taskgroup-in-airflow-2