# Dynamic TaskGroup in Airflow 2

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a function `run_step` that produces a dynamic number of emr tasks within a task group. I want to keep this function in a separate file named `helpers.py` so that other dags can use it and I don't have to rewrite it (in the examples below, I have hard-coded certain values for clarity, otherwise they would be variables):

```
def run_step(my_group_id, config, dependencies):
  task_group = TaskGroup(group_id = my_group_id)

    for c in config:
      task_id = 'start_' + c['task_name']
      task_name = c['task_name']

      add_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
          task_group=my_group_id,
          task_id=task_id,
          job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='my_dag', task_ids='emr', key='return_value') }}",
          steps=create_emr_step(args=config[c], d=dependencies[c]),
          aws_conn_id='aws_default'
      )

      wait_for_step = EmrStepSensor(
          task_group=my_group_id,
          task_id='wait_for_' + task_name + '_step',
          job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='my_dag', task_ids='emr', key='return_value') }}",
          step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='my_dag', task_ids='" + f"{my_group_id}.{task_id}" + "', key='return_value')[0] }}"
      )

      add_step >> wait_for_step

  return task_group
```

The code in `my_dag.py` which calls this function looks like:

```
execute_my_step = create_emr_step(
    my_group_id = 'execute_steps'
    config = my_tasks,
    dependencies = my_dependencies
)

some_steps >> execute_my_step
```

I am expecting this to produce a task group that contains two steps for every item in config, but it only produces one step labeled as `create_emr_step` with no task group. I tried putting the TaskGroup in the dag (and made the necessary changes to `run_step`) as shown below, but that did not work either:

```
with TaskGroup('execute_steps') as execute_steps: 
  execute_my_step = create_emr_step(
      my_group_id = 'execute_steps'
      config = my_tasks,
      dependencies = my_dependencies
  )
```

Is it possible to do this? I need to produce steps dynamically because our pipeline is so big. I was doing this successfully with subdags in a similar way, but can't figure out how to get this to work with task groups. Would it be easier to write my own operator?