# Insert values from airflow xcom into Bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I have saved values in xcom (key='db_value') in xcom in one of the airflow task. in one of the later step I need to save same value in Bigquery table.
Can you please suggest, how can I prepare SQL to update/insert table with XCOM values appended in SQL string and then pass same to BashOperator or PythonOperator or BigqueryOperator.
I tried using python callable or BigqueryOperator, but since task_instance.xcom_pull is not available till operator is executed, I am not able to prepare SQL before hand to provide same in param.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show the data structure of the data you saved to XCOM?

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to solve the issue. I have used approach provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168908/427766).
Had to execute another operator (BashOperator) inside PythonOperator. Otherwise I wasnt able to prepare SQL using xcom_pull values