# Create dynamic workflows in Airflow with XCOM value

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Now, I create multiple tasks using a variable like this and it works fine.

```
with DAG(....) as dag:
    body = Variable.get("config_table", deserialize_json=True)
    for i in range(len(body.keys())):
        simple_task = Operator(
            task_id = 'task_' + str(i),
            .....
```

But I need to use XCOM value for some reason instead of using a variable.
Is it possible to dynamically create tasks with XCOM pull value?

I try to set value like this and it's not working

`body = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='config_table', task_ids='get_config_table') }}"`

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to dynamically create tasks from `XComs` generated from a previous task, there are more extensive discussions on this topic, for example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow). One of the suggested approaches follows this structure, here is a working example I made:

sample_file.json:

```json
{
    "cities": [ "London", "Paris", "BA", "NY" ]
}
```

- Get your data from an API or file or any source. Push it as `XCom`.

```py
def _process_obtained_data(ti):
    list_of_cities = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data')
    Variable.set(key='list_of_cities',
                 value=list_of_cities['cities'], serialize_json=True)

def _read_file():
    with open('dags/sample_file.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        # push to XCom using return
        return data


with DAG('dynamic_tasks_example', schedule_interval='@once',
         start_date=days_ago(2),
         catchup=False) as dag:

    get_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_data',
        python_callable=_read_file)
```

- Add a second task which will pull from  pull from `XCom` and set a `Variable` with the data you will use to iterate later on.

```py
    preparation_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='preparation_task',
        python_callable=_process_obtained_data)
```

**Of course, if you want you can merge both tasks into one. I prefer not to because usually, I take a subset of the fetched data to create the `Variable`.*

- Read from that `Variable` and later iterate on it. It's **critical** to define `default_var`.

```py
    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
        trigger_rule='none_failed')

    # Top-level code within DAG block
    iterable_list = Variable.get('list_of_cities',
                                 default_var=['default_city'],
                                 deserialize_json=True)
```

- Declare dynamic tasks and their dependencies within a loop. Make the `task_id` uniques. `TaskGroup` is optional, helps you sorting the UI.

```py
    with TaskGroup('dynamic_tasks_group',
                   prefix_group_id=False,
                   ) as dynamic_tasks_group:
        if iterable_list:
            for index, city in enumerate(iterable_list):
                say_hello = PythonOperator(
                    task_id=f'say_hello_from_{city}',
                    python_callable=_print_greeting,
                    op_kwargs={'city_name': city, 'greeting': 'Hello'}
                )
                say_goodbye = PythonOperator(
                    task_id=f'say_goodbye_from_{city}',
                    python_callable=_print_greeting,
                    op_kwargs={'city_name': city, 'greeting': 'Goodbye'}
                )

                # TaskGroup level dependencies
                say_hello >> say_goodbye

# DAG level dependencies
get_data >> preparation_task >> dynamic_tasks_group >> end
```

DAG Graph View:

[image: DAG in the UI]

Imports:

```py
import json
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
```

Things to keep in mind:

- If you have simultaneous dag_runs of this same `DAG`, all of them will use the same variable, so you may need to make it 'unique' by differentiating their names.
- You must set the default value while reading the `Variable`, otherwise, the first execution may not be processable to the `Scheduler`.
- The Airflow *Graph View* UI may not refresh the changes immediately. Happens especially in the first run after adding or removing items from the iterable on which the dynamic task generation is created.
- If you need to read from many variables, it's important to remember that it's recommended to store them in one single JSON value to avoid constantly create connections to the metadata database (example in this [article](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f)).

Good luck!

Edit:

##### Another important point to take into consideration:

- With this approach, the call to `Variable.get()` method is [top-level code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code), so is read by the scheduler every 30 seconds (default of `min_file_process_interval` setting). This means that a connection to the metadata DB will happen each time.

Edit:

- Added if clause to handle emtpy `iterable_list` case.

Comment: nice, should note TaskGroup is 2.0+ feature only

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It was very helpful!!

Comment: Do note that this approach can only work if you run your airflow in a single server.
Once you do it with the Celery solution or something else, this will require a different way to sync the file into all workers.

Comment: @ZacharyaHaitin this works just fine with Celery Executor,  just make sure every worker you have is able to read the JSON file. The iterable list is read from a Variable which is take from the DB so no problem there either. Anyway, I believe that nowadays Airflow has an out of the box solution for dynamic task generation, docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Starting from Airflow 2 it's much easier to achieve, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907844/4039952). do note that dynamic tasks can still cause the issues I mentioned below.

---

This is not possible, and in general dynamic tasks are not recommended:

1. The way the Airflow scheduler works is by reading the dag file, loading the tasks into the memory and then checks which dags and which tasks it need to schedule, while xcom are a runtime values that are related to a specific dag run, so the scheduler cannot relay on xcom values.
2. When using dynamic tasks you're making debug much harder for yourself, as the values you use for creating the dag can change and you'll lose access to logs without even understanding why.

What you can do is use branch operator, to have those tasks always and just skip them based on the xcom value.
For example:

```
def branch_func(**context)
    return f"task_{context['ti'].xcom_pull(key=key)}"


branch = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="branch",
    python_callback=branch_func
)

tasks = [BaseOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}") for i in range(3)]
branch >> tasks
```

In some cases it's also not good to use this method (for example when I've 100 possible tasks), in those cases I'd recommend writing your own operator or use a single PythonOperator.