# How to invoke Python function in TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: python, airflow

In am trying to call DAG from another DAG( target_dag from parent_dag).

My parent_dag code is :

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

def read_metadata(**kwargs):
    asqldb_kv = Variable.get("asql_kv")
    perfom some operations based on asqldb_kv and populate the result_dictionary list
    if len(result_dictionary) > 0:
       my_var = Variable.set("num_runs", len(result_dictionary))
       ti = kwargs['ti']
       ti.xcom_push(key='res', value=result_dictionary)

            
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(year=2021, month=6, day=19),
    'provide_context': True
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='parent_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    description='Test Trigger DAG'
) as dag:

    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(

        task_id="test_trigger_dagrun",
        python_callable=read_metadata,
        trigger_dag_id="target_dag"
    )
```

I am getting the below error :

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to TriggerDagRunOperator (task_id: test_trigger_dagrun). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'python_callable': <function read_metadata at 0x7ff5f4159620>}
```

Any help appreciated.

**Edit :**

python_callable is depreciated in TriggerDagRunOperator - Airflow 2.0.

My requirement is :

I need to access Azure Synapse and get a variable (Say 3). Based on retrieved variable, I need to create tasks dynamically. Say, if Synapse has 3 , then I need to create 3 tasks.

My idea was :

DAG 1 - Access Azure synapse and get Variable. Update this to Airflow Variable. Trigger DAG2 using TriggerDagRunOperator.

DAG 2 - Create tasks depending on the Airflow Variable updated in DAG 1.

Any inputs how can I achieve this?

Comment: The documentation page I see does not show a `python_callable` parameter for `TriggerDagRunOperator`.  Where did you see that?

Comment: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-airflow/externally-triggered-dags-apache-airflow/read

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator

Comment: Ah, but that's `dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator`.  You're using `trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator`.  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html

Comment: Shame on them for having two different functions with the same name.

Comment: Well the documentation links reference vastly different Airflow versions with 1.10+ and 2.0+. Additionally, `airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator` is deprecated. 1.10.X reached end-of-life on June 17.  There was substantial module reorganization done with the 2.0.0 release

Comment: I am updating my question/requirement. Thanks.

Comment: @Madhanlal I think you can achieve what you want without even using a second DAG. [Check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907844/10569220).