# Airflow Broken DAG error during dynamic task creation with variables

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create dynamic tasks depending on airflow variable :

[image]

My code is :

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(year=2021, month=6, day=20),
    'provide_context': True
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='Target_DIF',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='@once',
        description='ETL pipeline for processing users'
) as dag:


    iterable_list = Variable.get("num_table")
    for index, table in enumerate(iterable_list):
        read_src1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'read_src_{table}'
            python_callable=read_src,
        )
        upload_file_to_directory_bulk1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'upload_file_to_directory_bulk_{table}',
            python_callable=upload_file_to_directory_bulk
        )
        write_Snowflake1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'write_Snowflake_{table}',
            python_callable=write_Snowflake
        )

        # TaskGroup level dependencies

        # DAG level dependencies
        start >> read_src1 >> upload_file_to_directory_bulk1 >> write_Snowflake1 >> end
```

I am facing the below error :

```
Broken DAG: [/home/dif/airflow/dags/target_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The key (read_src_[) has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively
```

The code works perfect with changes in the code :

```
#iterable_list = Variable.get("num_table")
iterable_list = ['inventories', 'products']
```

Start and End are dummy operators.
Airflow variable has data as shown in the image.

My expected dynamic workflow:
[image]

I am able to achieve the above flow with a list but not with Airflow variable.

Any leads to find the cause of the error is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are not handling the case where `table` is `None` . As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820948/create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow-with-xcom-value/66907844#66907844), set a a default param in `Variable.get()` or add an `if` clause before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to arrive at the solution with the followings modifications :

```
import ast
...
...
    iterable_string = Variable.get("num_table",default_var="[]")
    iterable_list = ast.literal_eval(iterable_string)
...
```

Airflow variables are stored  as strings.
So my data was stored as "[tab1,tab2]".
So I have used literal_eval to convert the string back to list.
I have also added an empty list as default so that if no values are present in the variable num_table, I will not process further.

Answer (score 3):

The `Variable.get("num_table")` returns string.
thus your loop is actually iterating over the chars of `['inventories, 'ptoducts']` which is why in the first iteration of the loop the `task_id=f'read_src_{table}'` is `read_src_[` and `[` is not a valid char for `task_id`.

You should convert the string into list.

Save your var as: `"inventories,ptoducts"` and then you can do:

```
iterable_string = Variable.get("num_table")
iterable_list = iterable_string.split(",")
for index, table in enumerate(iterable_list):
```

You should note that using `Variable.get("num_table")` as a top level code is a very bad practice!

Comment: Thanks Elad. I m creating dynamic tasks based on num_table variable which is updated by previous dag? Any inputs on good practice to handle this scenario?

Comment: This is not a good practice to begin with. Airflow expected as static workflows as possible. if the continent of the list is changed every time you should think of another design. For example: have all tables in the dag definition and in execution decide if you execute or not based on the variable. This way the usage of the variable is ok because it won't be in top level code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default, Airflow reads the variables as `str`. Try using this:

```py
iterable_list = Variable.get("num_table", deserialize_json=True)
```