# Airflow Dynamic dag creation based on the message passed from Master dag

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, orchestration

So I want to create a dag that creates dynamic tasks based on messages passed from the previous dag.
ex:-
I have a master dag and a slave dag.
from master dag, I pass a list of countries ex: [us,uk,fr] to slave dag
I want to read this message and create three tasks in  slave dag.

[image]

I was able to achieve this using the code below by saving those country's list in Variables and getting it in dag definition like the code below.

```
with airflow.DAG(
        'slave_dag',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

start= python_operator.PythonOperator(
            task_id = 'start',
            python_callable = start,
            retries = 1,
            provide_context = True,
            xcom_push=True
        )   
        
        params = Variable.get('countries')
        params=params.replace("'","")
        params = json.loads(params)

        for region in params['region']:

        region_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f"{region}",
            trigger_dag_id="another_dag", 
            params= {'condition_param': True,'marketplace': region},
            python_callable=trigger_dag,
            retries=1,
            retry_delay = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        )
        
        start.set_downstream(region_task)
```

but I don't want this I cant save it in variables as many master dags can call the same slave and pass different countries. so if two masters update the variable at the same time it will be a problem. so I need to get the value from master dag. we usually access the value passed in master dag in python function using this context['dag_run'].conf['message']

but I'm not able to access this in dag definition. is there any way to achieve this? or any other way I can create this dag.

Comment: So you managed to create dynamically our DAGs. So could you explain what the issue with an example ? Also, [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/creating-dynamic-composer-airflow-dags-from-json-template-90714af3b180) article explains another way to dynamically create DAGs. Would it help you?

Comment: as you can see from the code the list of countries I'm getting from params = Variable.get('countries') so now the this variable.get('conutries')  can be modified by n master dags. so lets say 1st master dag comes and says I wanna run the code for [US,UK] and updated the variable but at the same time some other master dag can come and say run for ["US","UK","FR"] we will end up with concurrency issues. so it will be better instead of wiring to a variable we can directly send the value from master dag to slave dag which we usually access in slave dag using context['dag_run'].conf['message']