# Dynamically generate multiple tasks based on output dictionary from task in Airflow

Tags: dictionary, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I have a task in which the output is a dictionary with a list value in each key

```
@task(task_id="gen_dict")
def generate_dict():
   ... 
   return output_dict # output look like this {"A" : ["aa","bb", "cc"], "B" : ["dd","ee", "ff"]}

# my dag (Not mention the part of generating DAG and its properties)
start = DummyOperator(task_id="st")
end = DummyOperator(task_id="ed")
output = generate_dict()
for keys, values in output.items():
   for v in values:
      dm = DummyOperator(task_id=f"dm_{keys}_{v}")
      dm >> end
        
start >> output
```

For this sample output above, it should create 6 dummy tasks which are dm_A_aa, dm_A_bb, dm_A_cc, dm_B_dd, dm_B_ee, dm_B_ff

But right now I'm facing the import error

```
AttributeError: 'XComArg' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is it possible to do what I aim to do? If not, is it possible to do it using a list like `["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"]` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question won't work as-is because the loop shown would run when the dag is parsed (happens when the scheduler starts up and periodically thereafter), but the data that it would loop **over** is not known until the task that generates it is actually run.

There are ways to do something similar though.

[AIP-42](https://wiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-42+Dynamic+Task+Mapping) added the ability to map list data into task kwargs in airflow 2.3:

```py
@task
def generate_lists():
    # presumably the data below would come from a query executed at runtime
    return [["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["dd", "ee", "ff"]]

@task
def use_list(the_list):
    for item in the_list:
        print(item)

with DAG(...) as dag:
    use_list.expand(the_list=generate_lists())
```

The code above will create two tasks with output:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

```
dd
ee
ff
```

In 2.4 the `expand_kwargs` function was added. It's an alternative to `expand` (shown above) which operates on dicts instead.

It takes an XComArg referencing a list of dicts whose keys are the names of the arguments that you're mapping the data into. So the following code...

```py
@task
def generate_dicts():
    # presumably the data below would come from a query made at runtime
    return [{"foo":6, "bar":7}, {"foo":8, "bar":9}]

@task
def two_things(foo, bar):
    print(foo, bar)

with DAG(...) as dag:
    two_things.expand_kwargs(generate_dicts())
```

... gives two tasks with output:

```
6 7
```

...and...

```
8 9
```

`expand` only lets you create tasks from the Cartesian product of the input lists, `expand_kwargs` lets you do the associating of data to kwargs at runtime.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Amazing stuff. Thank you for linking the confluence task API-42 as well. It was exactly what I needed to see how to make this work with my `DockerOperatorTemplated`. Pretty amazing feeling when you start using a tool and that feature you need was just added!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Now that it's released I made some edits. You might be interested in the new stuff in 2.4 as well. I find `expand_kwargs` to be more flexible than `expand`.