# Dynamic task creation in airflow dag

Tags: airflow

My requirement is to read process numbers from BigQuery table and pass that as input arguments to 5 python scripts. These process numbers can change. And for same process number the 5 scripts must run in sequence.

I have gone through [Proper way to create dynamic workflows in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow/51977800#51977800) and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html links, but I'm still not able to understand how to resolve my problem.

I've tried below code, which is working fine.  -

```
from airflow import DAG, models
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'retries': 0
}

mydict = {}
@task
def getdata():
    config={
        "job_type":"Query",
        "query":{
            "query":"select number,name from myproject.my_dataset.my_table",
            "useLegacySql":False,
            "allow_large_results":True,
            "location":"location_name"
        }}
    hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    target_data=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, project_id=None, nowait=False)
    for row in target_data.result():
        mydict[row.number] = row.name
    return mydict

@task
def task(arg):
    print(f'arg is -> {arg}')
    
with DAG('dynamic-dag',default_args=default_args,catchup = False) as dag:    
    task.expand(arg=getdata())
```

In the above code instead of "def task" I want to call those 5 python scripts with arg[0] as the input argument and also to define the dependency as sequential for the same process number (script_1>>script_2>>script_3>>script_4>>script_5) and to call the same set of 5 scripts in sequence with different process number.....
I don't know how to achieve this...

```
Bashoperator.partial(task_id="script 1", bash_command="python /home/airflow/gcs/scripts/script_1.py arg[0])
Bashoperator.partial(task_id="script 2", bash_command="python /home/airflow/gcs/scripts/script_2.py arg[0])
```

.....
.....

```
def task(arg):
    print(f'arg is -> {arg}')
```

Comment: FYI: Dyamic task mapping runs the tasks(index task) in parallel