# Airflow scheduler not picking up dags

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am currently having some issue with Airflow DAG execution.
Here's error code and I've attached airflow UI behaviors:

DAG Definition:
        default_args = {
            'owner': 'Analytics',
            'depends_on_past': False,
            'retries': 3,
            'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
            'start_date': suite_start_date
        }
        main_dag = DAG(dag_id=suite_name,
                       default_args=default_args,
                       schedule_interval=suite_schedule,
                       dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
                       max_active_runs=1
                       )

I am creating dynamic DAGs from user input: [Airflow dynamic DAG and Task Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133376/airflow-dynamic-dag-and-task-ids)

start_time and schedule_interval are dynamic in my Airflow setup.

> ---
>
> [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Some task instances failed:
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: {(‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_delta_window_set_start’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_process_hourly_start’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_device_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_player_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘collector_meta’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_delta_reprocess_set’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_device_attribution_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538))}
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: 
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py:23: FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: “flask_wtf.CsrfProtect” has been renamed to “CSRFProtect” and will be removed in 1.0.
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   csrf = CsrfProtect()
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/ti_deps/deps/base_ti_dep.py:100: DeprecationWarning: generator ‘_get_dep_statuses’ raised StopIteration
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,622] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   for dep_status in self._get_dep_statuses(ti, session, dep_context):
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/bin/airflow”, line 28, in 
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py”, line 422, in run
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py”, line 53, in wrapper
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py”, line 1390, in run
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py”, line 88, in execute
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     executor=self.executor)
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py”, line 3414, in run
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,626] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     job.run()
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py”, line 201, in run
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     self._execute()
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File “/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py”, line 2063, in _execute
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     raise AirflowException(err)
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: ---------------------------------------------------
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Some task instances failed:
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: {(‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_delta_window_set_start’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_process_hourly_start’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_device_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_player_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘collector_meta’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘meta_delta_reprocess_set’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538)), (‘Process_Hourly.process_hourly_1_meta’, ‘install_device_attribution_ff’, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 14, 19, 52, 22, 495538))}
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:34,627] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: 
>   [2017-11-14 20:26:36,319] {jobs.py:2125} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

Airflow task status
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also add your DAG definition?

Comment: Note that the logs you posted are for a SubDagOperator. You should click on that task and "Zoom into Sub DAG" instead of "View Logs", then you should be able to find out which task inside the Sub DAG is causing it to fail.

Comment: @Breathe , I updated my DAG definition. I am creating dynamic DAGs.

Comment: @DanielHuang hey that's what I did :) thanks