# Airflow: How to create child operators from inside python_callable in PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have a simple python operator, defined like so:

```
loop_records = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'loop_records',
    provide_context = True,
    python_callable = loop_topic_records,
    dag = dag    
)
```

This python operator calls `loop_topic_records`, defined like so:

```
def loop_topic_records(**context):
    parent_dag = context['dag']
    for i in range(3):
        op = DummyOperator(
            task_id="child_" + str(i),
            dag=parent_dag
        )
        logging.info('Child operator ' + str(i))
        loop_records >> op
```

I see that the code does not raise any errors. It even prints `Child operator 0..2` in the log. However, in the dag `Graph view` I do not see child operators, I just see only `loop_records` node, as if my dag consists only of one operator. So, what is wrong with that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I've just created on operatorm which must fail (I just put such a logic into this operator). However, when I run the whole dag, it runs successfully. So, it means that nested child operators called in this way never run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do what you want. Each DAG, once loaded by Airflow, is *static*, and can't be altered from a running task. Any alterations you make to the DAG from inside a task are *ignored*.

What you *can* do, is *start other DAGs*, using the Multi DAG run operator provided by the [`airflow_multi_dagrun` plugin](https://github.com/mastak/airflow_multi_dagrun); create a DAG of DAGs, so to speak:

```
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import DagRunOrder
from airflow.operators.multi_dagrun import TriggerMultiDagRunOperator

def gen_topic_records(**context):
    for i in range(3):
        # generate `DagRunOrder` objects to pass a payload (configuration)
        # to the new DAG runs.
        yield DagRunOrder(payload={"child_id": i})
        logging.info('Triggering topic_record_dag #%d', i)

loop_topic_record_dags = TriggerMultiDagRunOperator(
    task_id='loop_topic_record_dags',
    dag=dag,
    trigger_dag_id='topic_record_dag',
    python_callable=gen_topic_records,
)
```

The above will trigger a DAG named `topic_record_dag` to be started, 3 times. Inside operators in that DAG, you can access whatever was set as the payload via the `dag_run.conf` object (in templates) or the `context['dag_run'].conf` reference (in `PythonOperator()` code, with `provide_context=True` set).

If you need to do additional work once those 3 DAGs are done, all you need is add a *sensor* to the above DAG. Sensors are operators that *wait* until a specific outside piece of information is available. Use one here that is triggered when all the child DAGs are done. The same plugin has a `MultiDagRunSensor` that's exactly what you'd need *here*, it'll trigger when all DAGs started by a `TriggerMultiDagRunOperator` task are finished (succeeded or failed):

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.multi_dagrun import MultiDagRunSensor

wait_for_topic_record_dags = MultiDagRunSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_topic_record_dags',
    dag=dag
)

loop_topic_record_dags >> wait_for_topic_record_dags
```

then put further operators after that sensor.

Comment: is it possible to access the whole dag_run.conf instead of accessing each attributes separately inside the "with Dag() ...". I wanted to create a dynamic key-value list out of the dag_run.conf to pass it to the kubernetes operator instead of checking for each non-existent keys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is for creating child operators from within the python_callable function, but if that's not a strict requirement, you can just loop over the creation of the PythonOperator like so

```
op = DummyOperator(
  task_id="dummy",
  dag=dag
)

for i in range(3):
    loop_records = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'loop_records_{i}',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=loop_topic_records,
        dag=dag
    )
    loop_records >> op
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, I need to do it inside `python_callable`, because in real case number of loops depends on `xcom`. In `loop_topic_records` from my question I loop a static array, however, in reality it is dynamic and is based on `xcom`

Comment: Basically, Airflow can't do it, tasks are static and generates automatically before execution. But you can find w/a like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133376/airflow-dynamic-dag-and-task-ids